# Константа в языке Си

Tags: c

Почему код так работает (когда константу объявляем как строку):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define A "3"

int main(void){
    puts(A);
}
```

а так нет (константа число):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define A 3

int main(void){
    puts(A);
}
```

Что нужно исправить?

Answer (score 6):

[man puts](http://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=puts&category=3&russian=0) сообщает нам, что прототип у `puts()` такой:

```
int puts(const char *s);
```

То есть в качестве аргумента эта функция принимает указатель на `char`, а не число. Если нужно вывести число, то или [printf()](http://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=printf&category=3) с аналогами:

```
printf( "%d\n", A );
```

Или переводить число в строку, потом выводить (см. man sprintf).

Answer (score 2):

Во-первых, обязательно возвращайте код возврата из главной функции main(), с помощью `return(0)` или `exit(0)`.

Во-вторых, `puts(A);` принимает в качестве аргумента строку (указатель на строку), затем добавляет к этой строке символ новой строки `\n` и всё это дело выводит в STDOUT, то бишь на экран.

Если же вместо строки передать в *puts* число, то функция рассмотрит это число как адрес на какую-либо строку, как будто-то бы расположенную по этому адресу. Но по факту происходит попытка доступа к произвольной ячейке памяти, к которой, с большой вероятностью, у программы нет доступа. Поэтому ОС заблокирует данную попытку и выдаст ошибку: `Segmentation fault`.

В-третьих, что нужно исправить? Зависит от того, что нужно получить в ответе. Распечатать число? Для этих целей, как уже сказали в другом ответе подходит printf. Если же необходимо уж использовать `puts`, то нужно сделать преобразования числа к строке. Как вариант можно использовать sprintf.

Comment: В современном C (99) возврат 0 из main() - неявный, можно не писать.

Answer (score 1):

Ваша проблема связана главным образом с вашим заблуждением о том, что `#define` объявляет константу. Это неверно. Выбросьте учебник, в котором это написано. Или ткните носом вашего преподавателя в данный текст.

`#define` - макроподстановка, предназначенная для обработки препроцессором.

Настоящая константа в C записывается как:

```
const int alpha = 3;
const char beta[]="beta";
```

Разница состоит в том, что макроподстановку препроцессор чисто механически воткнет во все места в исходном тексте, где она встречается.

В то же время, константу обрабатывает компилятор, на более высоком, "умном" уровне. Обратите внимание, что у настоящей константы есть тип - это означает, что глупая ошибка вроде "число вместо строки" просто не откомпилируется. А вот с макроподстановкой такой номер может не пройти.

Одно из важных правил - макроподстановкам нужно всегда предпочитать константы, чтобы избежать чудесных глюков.

[Материал о константах](https://habrahabr.ru/post/301332/)

Comment: @Ilnyr,  `Одно из важных правил ...` - это для тех, кто не освоил макро. На самом-то деле общие "константы" связывают части системы в единое целое именно через макро в .h файлах (загляните в /usr/include)

Comment: @avp - поменяли одну константу - и побежали всю программу пересобирать, вместо одного объектника. Километры макросов - любимый бред программистов старой закалки, один только факт, что в Windows практически все системные вызовы - по факту макросы (с подменой на A и W - версии - костылять, так с музыкой), говорит о многом. Особым произведением макросного искусства является SDL от микроконтроллеров STM.

Comment: Так просто не надо локальные константы в общие .h помещать. А вообще, макросы на Си иногда позволяют просто чудеса творить. Только, конечно, надо знать меру, да и просто правильно проектировать систему.

Answer (score 0):

Если подвести итоги, то я согласен со всеми постами, с учетом одной поправки. Директива `#define A 3` задает символьную константу(литерал), а не число, как писали выше. Она(символьная константа) становится числом на этапе компиляции (после подстановки макроса, те сокращенного имени). Т.е. часть прототипа `const char *` говорит о том, что функция `puts()` ожидает указатель на неизменяемые данные типа `char`.

Указатель является переменной, в то время как строки `#define A 3` и `puts(A)` пытаются передать функции `puts()` числовую константу. (Кстати, компилятор тоже говорит, что у `А` тип `int`). Отсюда и проблемы. И не макроподстановок нужно избегать, а правильно следовать соответствию указанным типизациям.

PS Распечатать свое значение вы можете так `printf("%c %d\n", A, A);` и полюбоваться на странную картинку в придачу :)

Comment: `Т.е. часть прототипа const char * говорит о том, что функция puts() ожидает указатель на неизменяемые данные типа char` -- скорее `const char *` в прототипе говорит о том, что `puts()` эти данные менять не будет.

Comment: раз прототип для puts(), то она и не будет :)  те масло масляное

Comment: Не, @dio4, не поняли. `const char *` в  прототипе, говорит о том, что функции пофиг, изменяемые это данные или нет (поскольку она их менять не собирается), а вовсе не от том, что она `ожидает указатель на неизменяемые данные`

Comment: Я прошу прощения, но не поняли тут вы чего-то. Запись вида int puts(const char *s); говорит о том, что функ. ожидает указатель на данные типа char, к которым она должна относиться как к данным типа const те ДЛЯ нее эти данные являются НЕ изменяемые( и ей совсем это не "пофиг", если пользоваться вашим сленгом), потому как менять их ей нельзя. А значит, попытка их дальнейшего изменения в коде вызовет ошибку еще на этапе компиляции.Вот что я имел в виду. Ну а кто что понял, дело лично каждого. Предлагаю вам быть более корректным в своих оценках других людей.

Comment: А теперь **внимательно** прочтите слова из своего ответа -- `функция puts() ожидает указатель на неизменяемые данные` (отмечу отдельно -- **неизменяемые данные**). Эти слова можно трактовать как -- "в функцию нужно передавать неизменяемые данные" или даже -- "в функцию нельзя передавать изменяемые данные", что в корне неверно. В фунцию с прототипом `const char *` можно передавать **любые** (в смысле защиты от записи) данные, а вот в функцию с прототипом `char *` передавать константы не нужно. Надеюсь, теперь Вам понятно, что я имел в виду оставляя свой первый комментарий.

Comment: Вы выдергиваете слова из контекста ("отмечу отдельно.."). Я НЕ отдельно писал то, что писал, а в составе предложения (для этого они и существуют в великом и могучем). Прочитав фразу вы сделали поспешные выводы, не замечая картины в целом и не хотите сами этого понять. Далее (раз уж вы начали прения...) - где конкретно я писал  "в функцию нельзя передавать изменяемые данные"? Я не писал. Слова "Эти слова можно трактовать как ..." говорят как раз о том, что ВЫ ЛИЧНО трактуете это так, это- это субъективизм, а не истина в 1-й инстанции.

Comment: Продолжение спора считаю пустым и не продуктивным. Автор больше вопросов не задает. Причем, я тоже. Просто вы хотите оставить последнее слово за собой и только, но это никак не поможет автору поста. а вы ведь ему пытаетесь помочь или что-то мне доказать? Будьте корректны. Это не личная переписка, а форум. Мне лично можете написать в личку.

Comment: По поводу субъективной трактовки Вы абсолютно правы, поскольку *восприятие текста, очевидно, является субъективным*, а 1-й комментарий предназначен тем, кто прочтет данный текст так же, как и я. И никакого  спора тут по сути предмета я тут не вижу. Поэтому можем просто удалить все не относящиеся к делу комментарии.

Answer (score 0):

По крайней мере в GNU C препроцессоре есть такая штука, называемая [stringification](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html), которая позволяет преобразовывать аргументы макро в строковые константы
  (которые уже могут передаваться в `puts()`).

Можно написать, что-то в таком духе:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define A 33
#define S "33"

#define xstr(s) str(s)
#define str(s) #s


int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{

  puts("A name: " str(A));  // компилятор "склеивает" идущие подряд строковые константы
  puts("A value: " xstr(A));

  puts("S name: " str(S));
  puts("S value: " xstr(S));

  return puts("End") == EOF;
}
```

и получить

```
avp@wubu:hashcode$ gcc tt.c && ./a.out
A name: A
A value: 33
S name: S
S value: "33"
End
avp@wubu:hashcode$
```

такой результат.

Обратите внимание, для подстановки значения аргумента макро нужна их вложенность.

Comment: В студии 2015 это тоже работает.