# Вопрос по подстановкам #define языка СИ

Tags: c

Есть такой рабочий код:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define T 50
#define str(s) strk(s)
#define strk(s) #s

int main ()
{
 puts(str(T));
}
```

Мы знаем что `puts` по прототипу не сможет вывести число, только строки.
Я не понял, какую роль играют вот эти две строчки для вывода числа через подстановку (в нашем случае для T, вместо которого будет подставляться целое число) из puts:

```
#define str(s) strk(s)
#define strk(s) #s
```

И зачем мы делаем подстановку к функции `str(s)` эту функцию `strk(s)` с произвольным именем (вместо `str(s)` и `strk(s)` можно писать что угодно и программа все равно заработает без ошибок)? Напоследок, что означает `#s` в данном примере?

Comment: Вроде бы в [своем ответе](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/533734/232) я приводил вот эту ссылку -- https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html, в которой рассказывается об использовании символа  `#` в макросах...

Answer (score 5):

Это такой хитрый способ заставить С рассматривать 50 не как число (и приводить к типу `int`), а как строку «50» (и превращать в последовательность байтов `0x30 0x35 0x00`).

Это делается как раз макросом с решеткой:

```
#define strk(s) #s
```

Решетка служит указанием — «рассматривай всю бурду, что попала в `s`, как строку». Убедитесь с помощью [ideone](http://ideone.com/t9AY0P).

А этот макрос:

```
#define str(s) strk(s)
```

нужен для того, чтобы первая подстановка `#define T 50` раскрылась и заменилась на 50.

Если сразу сделать `strk(T)`, программа превратит T в строку и напечатает «T».

Это свойство можно использовать для формирования отладочного вывода:

```
#define PRINT(A) printf(#A " = %d\n", A);
```

Answer (score 4):

В дополнение. Посмотрим на это:

```
#define T 50
#define str(s) #s

int main() {
    puts( str(T) );
    return 0;
}
```

Прогоним через препроцессор и получим:

```
int main() {
    puts( "T" );
    return 0;
}
```

То есть в таком варианте макрос `str()` будет превращать в строку не *значение* аргумента, а его имя :) Дополнтельный прогон через ещё один макрос и нужен потому, что в него попадёт уже именно значение (в нашем случае - `50`).